# I get the error of Undefined variable $id even if it is passed

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I am using an optional parameter and am encountering the following error:

***Undefined variable $id***

even if it is passed in the route correctly.

Why am I getting this error? Can you help me please?

**Route**

```js
Route::get('/project/index/{id?}', [ProjectController::class, 'index'])->name('project.index');
```

**ProjectController**

```js
public function index($id=null)
    {           
        if($id){
            $projects = Project::withCount(['tasks'=> function (Builder $query){
                $query->where('project_id', $id);
            }])->get();
        } else {
            $projects = Project::withCount('tasks')->get();
        }
        return view('project.index', compact('projects'));
    }
```

**View**

```js
<tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>N. Task</th>
      <th>Azione</th>
</tr>
      @foreach ($projects as $project)
          <tr>
              <td>{{ $project->id }}</td>
              <td>{{ $project->name }}</td>
              <td><a href="{{route('task.index' , ['id' => $project->id])}}" class="link-primary">{{ $project->tasks_count }}</a></td>
              @endif
          </tr>
      @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `$id` to the `withCount` method with `use()`

```
$projects = Project::withCount(['tasks'=> function (Builder $query) use ($id){
    $query->where('project_id', $id);
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

First learn about route: [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-and-dependency-injection)

Remove `?` from route

```
Route::get('/project/index/{id}', [ProjectController::class, 'index'])->name('project.index');
```

change `ProjectController` function parmeter from

```
public function index($id=null)
```

to

```
public function index($id)
```

Done!!